# Downloading files in swift 3 only completes up to 24 kb? Using URLSession

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

I am using this [guide](http://sweettutos.com/2015/11/06/networking-in-swift-how-to-download-a-file-with-nsurlsession/) for downloading files in swift 3. I tried to manipulate it by adding a certain loop to be able to download n number of files. It works, yet it only completes up to 24 kb.

Here's my code:

```
for jsonDict in data{
  var jasonData = Attachment()

  if let data = (jsonDict["url"] as? String) {jasonData.url = data} else { jasonData.url = ""}

  self.beginDownloadFile(jasonData: jasonData)
}

func beginDownloadFile(jasonData: Attachment){
        let identifier = jasonData.customer_id + "/attachment/" + jasonData.patient_guid + "@%E%@" + "/" + jasonData.filename + "@%E%@" + jasonData.customer_id  + "@%E%@" + jasonData.patient_guid

        let backgroundSessionConfiguration = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: identifier)

        backgroundSession = Foundation.URLSession(configuration: backgroundSessionConfiguration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)

        var link = self.constants.PATIENTS_PICTURE_LINK + jasonData.customer_id + "/attachment/" + jasonData.guid + "/" + jasonData.filename
        link = link.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "%20")

        let url = URL(string: link)!

        downloadTask = backgroundSession.downloadTask(with: url)
        downloadTask.resume()
    }

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession,
                    downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask,
                    didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL){
        let string_container = session.configuration.identifier!.components(separatedBy: "@%E%@")

        let folderPath = string_container[0]
        let fileName = string_container[1]
        let customerID = string_container[2]
        let patientGUID = string_container[3]

        print("GUID IS: " + patientGUID)

        let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true)
        let documentDirectoryPath:String = path[0]

        let fileManager = FileManager()

        let path1 = documentDirectoryPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent(pathComponent: customerID)
        let path2 = path1.stringByAppendingPathComponent(pathComponent: "attachment")
        let path3 = path2.stringByAppendingPathComponent(pathComponent: patientGUID)

        let destinationURLForFile = URL(fileURLWithPath: path3.appendingFormat(fileName))

        do {
            if !fileManager.fileExists(atPath: path1) {
                try fileManager.createDirectory(atPath: path1, withIntermediateDirectories: false, attributes: nil)
            }
            if !fileManager.fileExists(atPath: path2) {
                try fileManager.createDirectory(atPath: path2, withIntermediateDirectories: false, attributes: nil)
            }

            if !fileManager.fileExists(atPath: path3) {
                try fileManager.createDirectory(atPath: path3, withIntermediateDirectories: false, attributes: nil)
            }

        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("ATTACHMENT ERROR: " + error.localizedDescription);
        }

        if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: destinationURLForFile.path){
            //showFileWithPath(path: destinationURLForFile.path)
            do {
                try fileManager.removeItem(at: destinationURLForFile)
                try fileManager.moveItem(at: location, to: destinationURLForFile)
                //showFileWithPath(path: destinationURLForFile.path)
            }catch{
                print("An error occurred while moving/deleting file to destination url")
            }
        }
        else{
            do {
                try fileManager.moveItem(at: location, to: destinationURLForFile)
                //showFileWithPath(path: destinationURLForFile.path)
            }catch{
                print("An error occurred while moving file to destination url")
            }
        }
    }
```

Result:

[Sample Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovy54.png)

What causes it to stop @ 24 kb? Is it because of the loop? or the identifier manipulation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

where is the code where you declare `downloadTask`? is it an instance property?

if so, then you are throwing away your pointer to `downloadTask` each time the loop runs, and this code gets ran:

`downloadTask = backgroundSession.downloadTask(with: url)
downloadTask.resume()`

it is possible that your task is being released early because of this. if that is the case, then the *last* time through the loop the download should complete.

also, is it possible that 24k is the correct file size? or maybe the size of a static error page?

Comment: Sessions retain the tasks in them.  However, assuming my limited Swift knowledge isn't misinterpreting what's happening here, the problem is that the code isn't retaining the **session**.

Comment: Hi! Sorry for the late reply, I only resumed coding earlier. It seemed that it was an error page. I-rechecked my links and it seemed there was a problem in its guid link part. Though it is working, am I doing the urlsession right? I'm putting the required data I need for filepath making in urlsession identifier.